# Sharing a file via Mediastore

Tags: android

I am trying to insert a file in MediaStore and then share the same file using the uri generated.

For Inserting the file

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    String fileName = "myFile.jpg";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);

    File enternalStroageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File file = new File(enternalStroageDir + File.separator + fileName);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String name = file.getName();
        String description = "My bitmap created by Android-er";
        String savedURL = MediaStore.Images.Media
                .insertImage(cr, imagePath, name, description);
```

Now, the insert is working fine as I checked in the gallery. 
Futher, to share the same image, I add the following code.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, savedURL);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SendText"));
```

However, when I choose any application that are suggested in the chooser, the sharing of file gets failed.
Any help will be appreciated.